# Expressjs host angular app with views - can't reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

So, I have this expressjs config:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"../../site")));
app.use("/src", express.static(path.join(__dirname,"../cms/src")));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile(site_public+'/index.html');
});


app.get("/admin/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,"../cms/index.html"));
});

app.get("/admin/css/*", function(req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,"../css/"+req.url.split("/admin/css")[1]));
});


app.get("/admin/*", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,"../cms/"+req.url.split("/admin/")[1]));
});


app.get("/:page", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(site_public+"/"+req.params.page+".html")
});
```

As you see, this hosts 2 things: a site_public folder, and an admin folder. `/admin`is a angularjs app, with views. The admin routes work relatively well as links or angular reroutes. Hovewer, if I was to hit refres on something like `/admin/dash`, which is an angular route, I'd get a 404, as by the last admin route. How could I fix this?

Comment: what a mess :( plesae make use of express static for serving all of the assets

Comment: yes, yes but that is not the problem. `admin/dash`is a view route which I can't refresh.

Comment: No one will reply unless your code starts to make at least some little sense. First thing for you to remember is that Angular is SPA framework, hence the only server .html file it cares about is index.html, and that's the only file you need to `sendFile`.

Comment: Second, good practice is to place the route to index.html in the format of `app.use('/*... res.render(index.html)`, and this route should come last

Comment: Reason is that whatever get request is sent from the client, unless it hits some api (remember index.html route comes last), server should keep giving the same index.html page , hence solving your refresh issue

Comment: Yerken, that _would_ work, if there'd be only one "/" route. However, in my case, everything, that is **not** `/admin/*` needs to be served by the last route (`/:page`), since site_public is a whole other directory. Everything that **is** `/admin/*`, should however  be served from admin.  Eg. `/myfunnyday`should be served by the last route, and `/admin/`by the admin routes.

Comment: Yerken, also a plain `/`should be rendered by the `/:page`route aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it myself. End solution looks like this for anyone who might need this.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"../../site")));
app.use("/admin/", express.static(path.join(__dirname,"../cms")));
app.use("/admin/src", express.static(path.join(__dirname,"../cms/src")));
app.use("/admin/css", express.static(path.join(__dirname,"../css")));

app.get("/admin/*", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,"../cms/index.html"));
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile(site_public+'/index.html');
});

app.get("/:page", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(site_public+"/"+req.params.page+".html")
});
```